# Django admin page

Tags: django, admin

I am relatively new to programming and would like to create a note sharing app with django. Is it possible to customize admin page for multiple type of users(super, regular, ordinary(read only) etc) and use it as a base for my application? and if yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

Basically by default in Django, there is 3 types of user: *super user*, *staff user* and *normal user*. If you use django's default user model, then if you go to the admin site(for example: `/admin/auth/user/<user_id>/change/`), then you should see this fields:

[image]

Based on the checkboxes you can identify the user types.

You can assign these users to specific models wise permissions as well:

[image]

There is more ways you can customize the adminsite and you can look into [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/) for adminsite customization.
You can give group permission as well and [check here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) for group permission and authorization.

But still, I would not recommend to use this as base of your application. As purpose of the adminsite is to provide support for the admin, not all users.  You can use adminsite to control permissions of the users to the actual dashboard.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Also, do you know where are the django admin models are?so i can see how they were created

Comment: @AlexS you can find admin implementations in [here](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin) and usage of django model admin site in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin)